# Threads and requests confusion

Tags: asp.net

If I have a site and each request has its own thread, does this mean that 1000 visitors will spawn 1000 threads? How does this work (obviously that can't be right)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Threads in ASP.NET are handled via a ThreadPool.

Requests are pooled across the ThreadPool, so each request can be handled by a different thread, but the threads can be reused, preventing the 1000 threads for 1000 requests scenario you mentioned.

For more details, see this [CodeProject article on Multi-Threading in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34639/Multi-Threading-in-ASP-NET.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is right. If you have 1 thread per visitor and 1000 visitors that makes for 1000 threads. It may not perform well, but that's another matter.

Fr multi-threaded server applications, you typically have 3 different allocation systems:

- 1 thread for all visitors - each one takes it in turn;
- 1 thread per visitor - obvious;
- a combination fo the 2 - 1 pool of threads (say 10) and visitors get 1 each until thet're all used whereupon new visitors wait.